# How to change the line width while plotting over the Bloch sphere

Tags: python, qutip

I am using QuTiP for the Bloch sphere plotting in Python. If I have several points on the Bloch sphere then I can connect them with a line using the command

```
b.add_points(pnts,meth='l')|
```

I wanted to know how can I change the linewidth of the line connecting these points.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way to do this, since by default no `linewidth` parameter is passed while making this plot, but you can always plot the lines manually.
The points need to be passed in as a list of `numpy.ndarray` objects.

The only catch is that to be consistent with what the `Bloch` class does, you need to make sure that the convention you are using to define the points is the same. It seems like the `l` method will only plot an connect the first three points that you feed in.

The following script reproduces this behaviour using a function that is similar to the one defined in `Bloch`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import qutip
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

pts = [np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5), subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.axis('square') 

b = qutip.Bloch(fig=fig, axes=ax)

for p in pts:    
    b.axes.plot(p[1], -p[0], p[2],
                alpha=1, zdir='z', color='r', 
                linewidth=5) 

b.render(fig=fig, axes=ax)
plt.show()
```

The output figure is here:

[image]